# Objective Sharpie: Binding a framework that imports headers from another library

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, clang

I'm using Objective Sharpie to bind a framework which imports a header from another framework and this is the error that I get:

```
/Users/sani/Documents/BindMeSDK/BindMeSDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/BindMeAppLinkResolver.h:19:9:
fatal error: 'AnotherFramework/BindMeAppLinkResolving.h' file not found

    #import <AnotherFramework/BindMeAppLinkResolving.h>
```

I tried including the BindMeSDK.framework path in the

> Advanced-> Follow #include and #import directives for files inside the
>   following scope directories:

but the error persists.

I was wondering if I need to set any flags in Objective Sharpie to include the other framework so Objective Sharpie can produce the proper API Definitions.

Does anyone have any ideas how to create API Definitions for frameworks with dependancy on another framework?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: No, never got it to work. Didn't know what to do. Decided to implement the logic in Mono instead of using the framework.

Comment: I subsequently found out you have to use -scope in your Sharpie call to stop it trying to bind header files outside the immediate library.